# Unconnected pads when updating footprints

Tags: pad

I got a regular footprint for a resistor, but I had to change it to a jumper so I updated the footprint to be like the photo below, but when I update the sch and pcb I lost one of the connections, I checked the sch it's connected, I updated more than once but still got the same prob
one of the pads is connected to the net but the other isn't,
why this might happen?
[image]

Comment: In the schematic, is pin 2 of the jumper symbol connected to the correct wire?